# Heating after fermentation?

Tags: yeast, fermentation-temperature, temperature, conditioning

What's the general consensus on leaving a heat source turned on after fermentation has complete?

I'm doing an Imperial IPA which should finish fermenting in 4-5 days going by previous experience with the yeast. I'm then going to leave it in the primary for 10-14 days for conditioning and possible dry hopping towards the end.

Is it best to leave my brewing mat turned on for the entire period or to turn it off once fermentation has completed?

I'm inclined to say yes... consistent temperature is always a good thing when dealing with yeast. Am I correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fermentation has finished and you're certain of that, the beer will benefit from getting it as cold as possible rather than leaving it warm.  Cold crashing, as it's called, will help drop the yeast and leave you with a clearer beer.  In addition, it will provide you with a crisper, cleaner flavor.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to say what kinds of bubble rate I would be seeing when fermentation is finished? I'm not expecting zero obviously, I just mean from the residual CO2 in the bucket

Comment: Bubbles are an absolutely inaccurate way pf predicting fermentation.  Bubbles can be released by temperature changes or other things.  The only way to know if fermentation is complete is to take specific gravity readings.  when there is no change in specific gravity, fermentation is done no matter what the bubbles are doing.